# HTML Optimization

Tags: html, css, optimization

I read this :

The browser retrieves all resources requested in the `<head>` section of the HTML before it starts rendering the `<body>`.  If you place the requests in the `<body>` section instead, then the page rendering and downloading resources can happen in parallel. You should move as many resource requests as you can from the `<head>` section to the `<body>`

the HTML specification calls for `<link>` and `<style>` tags the be in `<head>`, but browsers do not enforce this

Before I go ahead and take the advice from the author of this book - I am curious if this is true that all modern - commonly used browsers don't enforce where the links are , and also if doing this will cause any other problems that I do not know about

Comment: "*If you place the requests in the <body> section instead, then the page rendering and downloading resources can happen in parallel.*" - This is not true. As soon as the browser hits a `<script src="external.js">`, all rendering/parsing stops, until the script has been downloaded and executed.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - now that is another issue , is it better to set the src of an img at the very start of <body> with javascript - so that it will start to be downloaded immediatly , or will the process of stopping to read the script slow things down?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas i think the qouate is pointin to a scenario prior to hitting the script tag in body!

Comment: @ScottSelby Why are you setting the "src" with JavaScript?

Comment: @Anirudha The quote explicitly states that rendering and downloading happens in parallel. This is not true for scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Taken From (Read it!):**

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

**Put Stylesheets at the Top**

While researching performance at Yahoo!, we discovered that moving stylesheets to the document HEAD makes pages appear to be loading faster. This is because putting stylesheets in the HEAD allows the page to render progressively.

**Put Scripts at the Bottom**

The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

It is true to some extent. Run [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) on your page, it will tell many optimization techniques applicable to your page.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the spec. An invalid document will render in unpredictable ways. By all means put your scripts in the body, right before end body tag. But keep the [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) and [style](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) inside the head.

When in doubt follow the specs.

Comment: does the link to js file have to be before a function from that js file is called?  I think I remember having issues with that, and that is why I moved them all to the top

Comment: If you need the javascript to execute before the user starts interacting with your site i.e. before page load, then yes it must be called first. Other wise your fine. http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/ .